# Is there the possibility to control VSCode via Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am currently trying to automate the startup of my development environment with a small script. For this I need to start some Docker containers, launch VScode and run a compile command.
For this I have a few questions regarding VSCode:

Is it possible to pass the terminal in VSCode via the script/Ubuntu terminal with a command?

How can I load a workspace file in VSCode (not open it to see the content)?

Comment: vscode has a CLI, its called `code`. I guess you could start by doing `code --help`

Comment: Is there a reason you can't call the compiler from the script? You don't need VS Code to compile.

Comment: It's just a comfort thing. The terminal disappears in the background and I may miss a compile error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess Visual Studio Code tasks is what you are looking for. These are small json files, that contain calls to npm/npx scripts or even custom commands.

See [Integrate with External Tools via Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) for the official docs.

Here is an example from their website for a custom windows commandline script (they specifically mention that it will be `.sh` for a linux environment):

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Run tests",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "./scripts/test.sh",
      "windows": {
        "command": ".\\scripts\\test.cmd"
      },
      "group": "test",
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "new"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, to run it for example automatically after VSCode startup (when using a workspace), you see the [Run behavior](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_run-behavior). You will probably need the `folderOpen` option.